# Errors running the getting started Xamarin Project from Azure on Visual Studio Mac

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-cosmosdb, visual-studio-mac

I am trying out CosmosDB and Visual Studio Mac for the first time and I'm getting errors such as

`The base class associated with this Xaml file could not be found`

```
/Users/Downloads/DocumentDB-Quickstart-Xamarin/packages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.180/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.targets(3,3): Error MSB4018: The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/Downloads/DocumentDB-Quickstart-Xamarin/iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DocumentDBTodo.iOS.exe.mdb".
File name: '/Users/Downloads/DocumentDB-Quickstart-Xamarin/iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/DocumentDBTodo.iOS.exe.mdb'
```

All I did was

1. Create a cosmos db using the SQL/DocumentDB access
2. Click on quickstart and download the Xamarin cosmos db quickstart
3. Build and Run

Was there something in my setup that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template has not been updated with the latest Xamarin.Forms and VS is not being able to compile the code.

Update the Xamarin.Forms package manually by right-click (over the package) -> Update. Once updated clean and rebuild your project and you will be good to go.

Hope this helps.-